# Single MySQL query to select any rows that have certain cells that match each other

Tags: mysql, sql

The title is a little confusing, so let me explain. Say I have the following rows:

```
type        name            seeds       size

fruit       apple           8           22
fruit       orange          8           14
fruit       raspberry       83          6
berry       pomegranate     201         19
```

I want a query that will compare all the rows and return any rows where `seeds` matches any other row, and type is `fruit`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.seeds = t1.seeds
WHERE t1.type = 'fruit' AND t2.type = 'fruit' AND t1.name <> t2.name
```

**Edit**:

Based on your comment, to find items where `seeds` match, but `type` DOESN'T match, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.seeds = t1.seeds
WHERE t1.type <> t2.type
```

Comment: Is there a way that this could be done to find items where `seeds` match, but `type` DOESN'T match?

Comment: @Jake - See my edit. I have written another query where `seeds` match and `type` does not. You can continue to update the `WHERE` clause to suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry, last request (I'm trying these as I go and keep discovering small issues). Could I do it where `seeds` match, and `type` doesn't match, but at least one of the rows has type equal to a certain string?

Comment: @Jake - Add `AND t1.type = 'fruit'` to the end of the `WHERE` clause.